# TABPY tableau with Python Integration package problem

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, tableau-api

I am trying to integrate Python with tableau. I installed Tabpy package and I have python 3.7 with Anaconda. When I am trying to run my python code with tableau I am getting this problem -

An error occurred while communicating with the Predictive Service.
Error processing script
ImportError : DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Please let me know if you have any solution to this problem.

Thanks.
[image]

[image]